# How to display a div over other content and in the center of webpage using CSS?

Tags: css

How do I display a div over other content of webpage? This div must be centered vertically and horizontally as in this example:

[image]

I tried this:

```
<div style = "position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;">DIV content</div>
```

In this example only the left corner is centered and not div itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work.

```
div{
    position:fixed;
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
    margin:-300px auto auto -250px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The *-300 pixels* and *-250 pixels* are the negative half of the height/width of the div respectively.

There may be a better way of doing this, but this is a method I used a while back.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but the pixel values can easily be changed for percentages to make it look fine on any resolution.

Comment: Chris, unfortunately, div is not centered in your example :(

Comment: Here's a rough working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kUb2S/ - I changed the position to fixed so that it remains in place when scrolling, and added a text-align.

Comment: Chris, yes, this works. Could you edit your answer? I will accept it then.

Comment: There you go. Glad I could help!

Comment: using margins with widths and heights is troublesome with IE6. Also negative margins are a bit frowned upon